# Encrypted home folder and programs working while screen is locked?

Tags: encryption

Is the home folder encrypted while the screen is locked and what happens with programs running in the background that need to access it if it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your homedrive gets "decrypted" at the time you login. When you lock your screen you're still logged in, so your homedrive is unencrypted and programs wich have the permission to access your homedrive can access it.